# What is the limit in mq_unlink?

Tags: c++, posix

[Documentation for mq_unlink](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mq_unlink) says

> ENAMETOOLONG
>       name was too long.

but what is this limit? I thought it is `NAME_MAX`, but it's not. The following code runs forever (as long as there is memory, I guess).

```
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <string>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    std::string tooLong = "long";
    do
    {
        usleep(10);
        tooLong.append("longer");
        mq_unlink(tooLong.c_str());
    }
    while(errno != ENAMETOOLONG);
}
```

So what is the limit? When does this function return `ENAMETOOLONG`?

Comment: You should check the return value of the function before you assume there's an error. It also seems like your name may be in the incorrect format. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html

Comment: as far as I can test, it stops when the string becomes 257 characters long, i.e. longer than `NAME_MAX` of 255.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, you are right.

The problem was the missing slash!

```
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <string>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)
{
    std::string tooLong = "/long";
    do
    {
        usleep(10);
        tooLong.append("longer");
        mq_unlink(tooLong.c_str());
    }
    while(errno != ENAMETOOLONG);
    std::cout << tooLong.length() << " " << tooLong << std::endl;    
}
```

This works and the length is 257 which is right above NAME_MAX.

Comment: "The problem was the missing slash!", no the problem is that you don't look the error value of `mq_unlink()`. You could avoid this question is you have good practice, please read [a book of C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?noredirect=1&lq=1)